# How do I favourite an item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I'm playing on a PC and all of my keybindings have been rebound since I'm left-handed. Having a hard time figuring out which button favourites - I thought it would be the sheathe button like on Xbox, but that simply drops my item.

Which button favourites the item? Please note I don't want to know which letter it is on the keyboard, I want to know what button it says on the controls menu (i.e. if it's the "activate" button or the "sprint" button or whatever).

Comment: Just re-read the question - not sure how I missed that crucial bit of information about not wanting the letter...Oops! Removed my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On PC it is the "Change POV" button.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ***Toggle POV*** button. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the "toggle POV" (change between 1st and 3rd person view).
Usually this would be "f" key, but you don't want to know that ;)